# Reading from authentication cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to read the username from an auth ticket (which is `TESTTEST`)

-----LOGIN PAGE------

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
      "TESTTEST",
      DateTime.Now,
      DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
      false,
      String.Empty,
      FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(
                            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                            encryptedTicket);
            authCookie.Secure = true;
            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
             FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("User", false);
```

------Protected page -------

```
 HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            Label1.Text = ticket.Name;
```

Results : label text is `"USER"` instead of `"TESTTEST"`

What can I do to fix this and get the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` creates a new ticket with supplied name ("User" in your case). From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx

> If the CookiesSupported property is true, and either the ReturnUrl variable is within the current application or the EnableCrossAppRedirects property is true, then the RedirectFromLoginPage method issues an authentication ticket and places it in the default cookie using the SetAuthCookie method.

You may want to use the following code instead of RedirectFromLoginPage

```
returnUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(userName, false);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
```